# Changing opacity on scroll sequentially for all divs in a class/on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, opacity

I've been working with changing the opacity of some divs dynamically based on scroll and page location. I've made a bunch of progress, but I've gotten caught up on three minor issues.

I have a top div with two "covered" divs one after the other below it. I want the opacity of each cover to slowly decrease as I scroll past its top, and then once the bottom of the page passes the middle of the cover I want it to finish fading out.

My current issues are:

1. The cover divs are fading simultaneously, and I want each to do its fading as its own top enters the screen (one at a time as you scroll down)
2. For the "reveal" (once the bottom of the window passes halfway on the cover) there is a flash of the cover becoming suddenly solid and then doing the fadeOut instead of just fading out from its current opacity.
3. The fading is seemingly being done by amount of scrolling and not location of page bottom. i.e if I make the window really short, then by the time I've scrolled down to see the top of the first div, the cover is already completely gone.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sT = $(window).scrollTop(), wH = $(window).height();
  $('.color').each(function(){
    var ths = $(this);
    var targetHeight = ths.outerHeight();
    var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
      if(scrollPercent >= 0){
        ths.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
      }
      if(sT + wH > ths.offset().top + (ths.height())/2){
      ths.fadeOut(2000);
      }
  });
});
```

And here is a JS fiddle of what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/690/

Anything you guys can do to help with any of my 3 issues would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was on purpose, but I think you're calculating the scroll percentage in a wrong way. I used this scroll percentage calculation:

```
var targetHeight = ths.outerHeight();
var relativeToViewport = ths.offset().top - sT;
var scrollPercent = 1 - (targetHeight - relativeToViewport) / targetHeight;
```

The flickering appears, because the `fadeOut` function is called everytime the scroll event is fired and the `div` passed the bottom halfway. You should save this state by using a class (or variable), e.g.:

```
$('.color:not(.hide)').each(function(){
    ...
    if((relativeToViewport + ths.height()) < wH){
        ths.fadeOut(2000);
        ths.addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

You can see my solution in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/692/)

Comment: Sebastian, thank you so much for your help with this!  You were right about the scroll percentage calculator I think. The only issue is that the gradual percentage-fading doesn't work on the last div if the second div is more than half in the window at the start (does that make sense?). Do you have any thoughts on that? Also, thank you for explaining the cause of the flickering!

Comment: You're welcome! I don't have this problem in Chrome (38). Which browser do you use?

Comment: hmm, that small hiccup happens for me in Chrome(37), Safari(7.0.6), and Firefox(32).